# Tortoise SVN showing 'Access to '/!svn/me'' forbidden error.

Tags: plugins, git, svn

I recently want to commit a change to my WordPress plugin repo but it has been showing  'Access to '/!svn/me' forbidden' error whenever I wanted to commit any changes. Some articles have adviced me to check if my username and password are correct but it seems not to be the right solution because my login credentials are actually correct.

Please, has anyone faced this issue before or is there an alternative to TortoiseSVN that I can use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

login case sensitive. Do not write from Uppercase